# RestKit how to check for wrong username or password error

Tags: passwords, restkit

I want to be able to notify the user if he entered the wrong username/password, or if for example the database is down. I am not sure if I need to do it in the didLoadResponse and just check that the response is not isOK or in the didFailLoadWithError.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you handle it depends on how you perform a login.

If you do basic authentication, by passing the username and password in the header of the request, then you'll get an error back from the service you're calling. And your delegate method, "objectLoader:didFailWithError:" method will get called. This method will most likely get called if there's a catastrophic problem on the backend, like the database being down.

If you have a separate webservice that performs a login operation, then it probably sends back a valid block, indicating whether the user-pass was valid or not. In this case, your "objectLoader:didLoadObject:" method probably got called, and you'll have to decipher the result appropriately.

Keep in mind that this behavior is totally controlled by what the back-end services do. If you can't talk directly with the people working on the services, then this may just be trial-and-error, and until you discover how those services work.